# No solution, how to understand finding a quantity value for reverse computing an average?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

I had this situation that I wanted to understand how many purchases at 60 dollars each would it take to average the total purchases out to about 60 dollars when one purchase was 48,000 dollars. This is assuming all purchases besides the one 48K purchase were 60 dollar purchases. I thought this equation represented the question

$$\frac{60x + 48000}{x+1}=60.$$

But apparently it's not because the above equation is unsolvable.
Could someone explain how to find the answer to a question like this please?
thank you

Comment: The (education) tag is completely irrelevant here and should only be used for questions on pedagogy (*which is generally better suited for the matheducators stackexchange than here*).  As for your question itself, you will need to clarify what you mean by "average... to **about 60 dollars**."  As the number of purchases grows, the average will *approach* 60 dollars but will never quite reach it.

Comment: You could answer the question of how many \$60 purchases it would take along with the one \$48,000 purchase to make the average \$61, or \$60.50, etc... or in general \$60$+\epsilon$ for some specifically stated $\epsilon>0$, but as you noticed it is impossible for a finite number of purchases at \$60 and one purchase at \$48,000 to average to exactly \$60.

Comment: @JMoravitz I have no idea what pedgogy is or what you mean, Thank you for the category/tag edit user7530

Comment: from google: "ped·a·go·gy
ˈpedəˌɡäjē/
noun
noun: pedagogy; plural noun: pedagogies

    the method and practice of teaching, especially as an academic subject or theoretical concept."

Comment: As for your question, I'll try to rephrase it.  The average of a finite collection of numbers, all of which are greater than or equal to 60 and at least one of which is strictly greater than 60 will always be strictly greater than 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one purchase above $60$ dollars, no number of purchases at $60$ dollars will bring the average down to $60$.  The average will always be (maybe very slightly) above $60$.  The equation you give is correct and the fact that it cannot be solved is evidence of my claim in the first two sentences.  Note that if your subsequent purchases were at $59$, the equation would become $\frac{59x+48000}{x+1}=60$ which can be [solved](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(59x%2B48000)%2F(x%2B1)%3D60) to give $x=47940$